¿Cómo generar un HASH de todas las columnas de un tabla?
Necesito generar un hash (me es indistinto el algoritmo) sobre todas las columnas de la tabla. Entiendo que podría hacer algo así:
SELECT  hashbytes('MD5',col1 + col2 + col3)
        FROM Tabla;

El problema de esto es no es una solución genérica, se necesita completar todas las columnas de la tabla y lidiar con los tipos de datos y sus conversiones y por supuesto los null. ¿Hay una forma más generalizable de hacerlo?

Es posible realizar una "representación" de cada fila en formato xml y sobre las mismas aplicar el hash:
Ejemplo:
SELECT  hashbytes('MD5', (
    SELECT  t.*
        FOR XML PATH('row')
    ))
    FROM sys.tables t;

El número generado obviamente no es el mismo que si lo aplicarás sobre la concatenación de cada columna, pero es un hash válido como representación de cada fila.
